# Why application:start(disk_log) response error?

Tags: erlang

I want to start disk_log with application:start/1, but it gives error.

When use disk_log:start/0, it give ok.

```
(fish@yus-iMac.local)6> application:start(disk_log).
{error,{"no such file or directory","disk_log.app"}}
(fish@yus-iMac.local)7> disk_log:start().
ok
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

disk_log is not an application, but a service which belongs to the kernel application. So you cannot start it using application:start(disk_log), and it has not its own version (it is included in the kernel one).